# Setting XslCompiledTransform Outputsettings

Tags: c#, .net, xslcompiledtransform

I am writing bit of code that relies on XslTransformation of one submodule.

Since the XslTransformation exposes a XmlWriterSettings field called Outputsettings I thought it would be cool to expose the XmlWriterSettings field in my class too so I can use my IoC container to configure the XmlWriterSettings through the configuration.

But as it turns out, Outputsettings is a readonly field and I can't find a way how to pass one to the Transform (no ctor overloads etc).

Am I missing something or is there maybe some Factory method for creating XslCompiledTransform with a given XmlWriterSetting?

greetings Daniel/Tigraine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://blogs.msdn.com/eriksalt/archive/2005/07/27/OutputSettings.aspx